# python errors unresolved import and Unused import in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am building a sample CRUD REST API project using Python & Flask, I am using VSCode to build this sample API Project. I am getting below errors/Warnings( see the attached Screenshot). I tried to run the project and tried using Postman to do GET request but getting 404 errors.

[image: Errors/Warning]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, it's more helpful to paste your error messages/code/dir structure as text. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You are describing 2 different issues here. One is the warnings, and one is your unexpected 404 result. It would be helpful to describe the core problem a bit more, as you have way more information than we do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings are correct. You have misspelled `__init__.py` as `__int__.py`, so python doesn't recognise the directory as a module. This is why it cannot find `Task`

As for the unused imports, why do you need an asterisk import (`from api import *` ? If you only need `appMainInstance` then you should only import that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer